# Git : how to remove a directory from working tree but keep it in the index?

Tags: git

I have a specific situation where I need to work on a specific package composed of 2 git repo, and still be able to commit/push on each repo.

Here is a simplified example :

- **repoA** with dirs **dirA**, **dirB**, *dirB/dir2*
- **repoB** with dirs **dirC**, **dirB/dir1**
- I need to work on a package containing : **dirA**, **dirB**, **dirB/dir1**, **dirC**

Here is what I did :

1. I began by cloning both repos.
2. Then I added in repoA clone dir a .git/info/exclude file containing : dirB, dirC
3. Then I created in repoA clone dir 2 symlinks to repoB dirB/dir1 and dirC.
4. Finally I removed in repoA clone dir dirB/dir2.

Here is what I get in the repoA clone dir :

- dirA
- dirB/dir1 (symlink to repoB)
- dirC (symlink to repoB)
- `git status` giving deleted files in dirB/dir2

This is nice for repoB as I can commit and push my changes without any problem. But for repoA, of course I don't want to commit/push the dirB/dir2 removal... Is there anything in git allowing to keep a dir in the index but don't show it in the working tree ?

For now I see two possible solutions that are not really nice for us :

- create a third directory containing symlinks to needed files in repoA and repoB... but this would cause lots of extra work as repoA contains in reality lots of dirs !
- create a dedicated branch in repoA from develop branch without dirB/dir2. To ease future merge, merge the new branch back to develop without the dirB/dir2 removal. Not that fine as it would force to create one dedicated package branch per repoA branch we need to work on...

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated O:)

Comment: Looks like you need [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: Ok, but I'm a bit ignorant of submodules... How would you achieve this using submodules ?

Comment: Sent you the doc, read it. Read The Full Manual